# How to keep previous directory in CtrlP?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

Using the CtrlP plugin, I'm typing `..` several times to get to the root directory of a project, then perform the search from there.

However after I reopen CtrlP it still searches in the directory of the current file.

How can I get it to stick to the directory that I originaly set ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By reading its documentation, of course.

- If you want CtrlP to *always* open in your project's root directory, if applicable, just add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

  ```
  let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode=2
  ```
- But you could also use both `:CtrlP` to browse in the current directory and `:CtrlpRoot` to browse in the root of your project.
- Or simply use `:CtrlPLastMode` to launch CtrlP in… the last mode.
- If your project doesn't fit CtrlP's definition of a project, a simple mapping could be enough:

  ```
  nnoremap <key> :CtrlP /path/to/project<cr>
  ```

  or you could use this option:

  ```
  let g:ctrlp_root_markers = ['']
  ```

***edit***

My answer was based on the version of CtrlP currently installed on my machine.

The latest version adds an optional argument to `:CtrlPLastMode`: `--dir` which does exactly what you are looking for:

```
:CtrlPLastMode --dir
```

The `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode` values are different, too. I believe `r` is the equivalent of `2`.

Comment: k, but none of these suggestions seem to be the answer. I don't see the option '2' in the docs, the available options for `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode` seem to be `c, a, r, w or 0`. Also CtrlP seems to identify a project by some dir that has a `.git` file inside. I just want it to stick to the last dir I searched in. If this stuff is not possible I'll just take it as an answer.

Comment: got it. `:CtrlPLastMode --dir` does the job

Comment: actually it seems like opening another file changes the working dir...so that option is pretty much useless. Guess the solution is to just touch a `.git` file in the project dir.